# How does unboxing work in short-circuited boolean expressions?

Tags: java, primitive, primitive-types, boolean-expression, unboxing

I recently tried to run the following two snippets of code and was surprised at the output.

First:

```
// ...
System.out.println( (Boolean)null || true );
// ...
```

Second:

```
// ...
System.out.println( (Boolean)null || false );
// ...
```

The first example results in the following output: 
true

The second example results in the following output: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
   at com.blah.main(SanityCheck.java:26)

I would have thought both examples should result in a null pointer exception, as any short-circuiting is applied left-to-right. The attempt to unbox the boolean from the Boolean should have failed before the other side of the logical or was given consideration.

Can anyone explain this inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: This behavior appears inconsistent with the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) "At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a jab at it.
As the compiler attempts to interpret the two statements, the main difference is that the statement with true on the right side is not required to make a computation with the left handed Boolean, while the statement with false on the right side is.

A Boolean is an Object, thus it can be set to null. That is not where the exception is thrown. The NullPointerException is thrown when you attempt to execute an operation on a Boolean object that is set to null. In the true case, the compiler will pass casting null to a Boolean, and because OR'ing with true will always yield true, the conditional is true. In the false case, the compiler will pass casting null to a Boolean again, it will then check false, and if the condition is false, it needs to compute the OR with the Boolean because the condition could ultimately come out as true or false. When the computation happens, the NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I thought that any short circuiting took place left to right. If the left operand is true in an or, the right operand is not evaluated. Similarly, if the left operand it true in an and, the right operand is not evaluated. I'm guessing it might be some optimisation by the compiler, so I'll try to decompile the class file.

Comment: I actually think I misread what you wrote - the short-circuiting isn't even applied because this is optimised out at compile time. Spot on.

Comment: Correct! Casting passes, and true passes. Then there's no need to true OR * because it will always be true

Comment: The important thing to note is that casting `null` to a `Boolean` does **not** throw a NullPointerException.  Whether or not the first example throws a NullPointerException seems to vary based on the JDK implementation (based on answers below).

Answer (score 4):

I ran the class file through JAD to see what the optimised code looked like. For the true case:

```
// ...
System.out.println(true);
// ...
```

For the false case:

```
// ...
System.out.println(null.booleanValue());
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your results. I actually get NPE for both cases.

As per JLS, the left-hand operand expression is always evaluated first. When `(Boolean)null` is evaluated, an auto unboxing is performed on a null Boolean object. In particular, the underlying code `null.booleanValue()` is causing the NPE.

Comment: You shouldn't get a NPE for the true case. (Boolean)null runs just fine on its own. Even if it is evaluated first, it shouldn't throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: @user1549672 It is really happening to me, so I'm still trying to figure out the problem. Does the result depend on the JDK version I'm using?

Comment: I'm not sure. Which version are you running?

Comment: @user1549672 I'm using the default JDK bundled with Netbeans 7.3.

Comment: @user1549672 I suspect it is a result of compiler optimization. In the true case, the expression is done evaluation at compile time so no NPE is thrown at run time. I believe my version of compiler does not support this kind of optimization.

Comment: Hm, I guess it could be a difference in JDK versions. Could be worth looking into!

Comment: @TerryLi - Here's my take: Casting null to a Boolean does not throw a NPE, so the difference you're witnessing must be attributed to different optimizations performed by different compiler implementations (for example OpenJDK vs Oracle JDK).

Comment: I'm using javac 1.7.0_03 and java 1.7.0_25-b17.

Comment: i'm also using a 1.7 build

Comment: I also get a NPE for both cases. I'm using Sun's JDK 1.6.0_21-b06 on Ubuntu 12.04 (installed years ago).

Comment: If I had to guess I would say the implementation matters more than the version number.

Comment: @jahroy I agree with you that implementation makes the difference.